# Heroku does not update node.js > package.json Github tarball dependecies

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I am managing a dependency at Github which I use as a dependency in my project. I placed the dependecy as a tarball link (viz. https://github.com/username/dependecy/tarball/master) into the package.json and it is working fine as expected locally. When I update the package at Github I can run a `npm install` and all dependencies including the Github tarballs get updated. However it is not the case at Heroku. tarball-linked dependencies does not get updated. Any ideas?

Comment: I am having this same problem. In the past I had been able to trick it by incrementing the version of the dependency but that isn't working now.

Comment: here is my workaround for now. Just change the username in the url and do a dummy commit. (maybe just put the url of a fork) Than change again to the original and commit again. Hope this helps

Comment: or just push node_modules folder to heroku.

Comment: I have considered including node_modules in my repo. Its bad practice but my heroku build times are starting to become a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has answered this yet I will share what I have learned. The trick is getting heroku to think the tarball is different or new so that it downloads it again. As @celalo suggested you can remove it or change the path, commit, push, change it back, commit and push. This is messy but it works.

What I ended up doing was making a master1 branch. I keep the branch in sync with master and then alternate the tarball url between master and master1 when I need it to update.

Comment: Visiting this in 2020 with exactly the same problem. Did you ever find a better way of doing this? I have been using the same workaround at you by changing branches but it's cumbersome and far from ideal.

Answer (score 4):

I had the similar problem. My App had the dependency with caret versioning like this:

```
"dependency": "^0.6",
```

So every time the dependency got its patch version updated, I wanted Heroku to have the updated dependency without any commits/pushes to my App. For that I set just in case

```
heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
```

And when the new patch version became available I did the manual redeploy of the same App that was already deployed from Heroku Dashboard.
[image]
Can you try to do the same for your case? Possibly this will help you.